# How to show line numbers of a python notebook in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I think it should be quite straightforward, however, I cannot seem to find this option in visual studio code.

Could you tell me if it is possible and how to enable line numbers in visual studio code when coding in a python notebook?

FYI: it is possible to use visual studio code with a python notebook (you can check more info [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support))

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62698920/line-numbers-for-every-cell-in-vscode-jupyter-notebook-cells for more on notebook line numbers.

Answer (score 14):

You have to press <kbd>L</kbd> after clicking on the left side of the code block.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

as mention in the link provided you just need to press the `L` key
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_enabledisable-line-numbers